# Silk Test doesn't identify WPF control hosted in Windows Forms host

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, silktest

I have a simple WPF user control:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button>Test</Button>
    <TextBox>Test</TextBox>
    <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

I am hosting this user control inside Windows Forms host. Silk Test identifies this entire user control as `Element-Host` only and is not able to identify individual buttons or text-boxes.

Has anybody more insight on this? Is this scenario supported by Silk Test?

**Update :**

I have little success with **Silk Test 14.0** (Earlier i had 13.5). Created test application with similar structure (WPF Control in windows forms host) and checked with **Silk Test 14.0**. It is able to detect all individual WPF controls within user-control . But with my application, it is still not able to detect controls apart from 2 combo-boxes in "Toolbar". In user-control, i am using custom grid which is derived from Data-grid class

Comment: By the way, there is already **Silk Test 15 Update 1** available. If 14 doesn't work for you, you might want to try the most recent version.

Comment: Yes, i have tried with **Silk Test 15 Update 1**  but with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silk Test team has identified this to be a bug. Fix may be released as a patch over Silk Test 15.5 version. I will update this post once i have better details on its release.

Answer (score 1):

**This should work.**

It might depend on how you are embedding the `UserControl` though.

In the application we are using for testing it is contained in a Windows Forms `ElementHost`-control.
In the code-behind you should see member declarations for both the `ElementHost` and your `UserControl`, is this the case?

Is your application using multiple `AppDomain`s? Silk Test currently only supports multiple AppDomains for Windows Forms, not for WPF so this might be another reason why it isn't working for you.

Comment: No, application is not using multiple AppDomain. Yes, members are declared in "Designer.cs" file and i can access them in code behind file. Editing question for some observations/updates

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Silk Test well but it seems to me that this tool supports only standalone WPF applications. In your case, there is a standalone WinForms application with embedded WPFs controls. Documentation says:

*Silk Test Workbench provides built-in support for testing Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications. Silk Test Workbench supports **standalone** WPF applications and can record and play back controls embedded in .NET version 3.5 or later.*

Comment: "[...] and can record and play back controls embedded in .NET version 3.5 or later." - I believe this should mean that it will also work for embedded controls, although the phrasing might be ambiguous.